# deploy shiny's publish button from R function-script

Tags: r, shiny

I have some code that reorganizes some spreadsheets and then creates a shiny from the spreadsheet. All of this code sits in a master script within functions. This way, when I need to run a particular function I just source the master script and run the function.

Is it possible to publish the output onto shinyapps.io without physically pushing the publish button? I just want to be able to run the function and have it publish automatically.

edit 1:  is there was a way I could make "appDir" = "some function in my master script"?

edit 2: Fixed the problem to edit 1. Don't put shiny code within a function.

edit 3: Is there a way to call the app.R file and my .csv file in rsconnect if they are in different locations?

Comment: if you have already deployed your shiny app, running ```rsconnect::deployApp(/path/to/your/app)``` will update its content so maybe if you put this function at the end of your script, your app will update each time you run the whole script

Comment: that does work, thank you. But I was wondering if there was a way I could make "appDir" = "some function in my master script"?

Comment: I don't see why you would like to put your working directory in a function in your master script, but the ```getwd()``` function shows you the path to your current directory so you could use it

Comment: I got rsconnect::deployApp(/path/to/your/app) to work within my master script as long as it is not set in a function. Is there a way to call the app.R file and my .csv file in rsconnect if they are in different locations?

Comment: check the documentation of ```deployApp``` function, you might find what you want (maybe with ```appFiles```, ```appPrimaryDoc```...) but I never used these functions

Comment: I kept getting errors with them. I tried appSourceDoc but and it seemed to work but could not find my .csv file

Comment: it is quite hard to know what you are trying to do, can you show a reproducible example ?

Comment: basically the error just says it can't find the csv file. it would be difficult to show a reproducible code. my script is pretty long